# Constructing tables in POWERBI DAX query

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi, dax

I have a table imported from excel into PowerBi, called `Events`

| Subgroup | Events | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 5 | 2022-12-01 |
| B | 4 | 2023-02-11 |
| C | 6 | 2022-10-13 |
| A | 1 | 2023-03-22 |
| B | 2 | 2022-10-23 |
| C | 4 | 2021-10-12 |

I need to make a new table from this table using DAX, called `Events summary` like:

| Subgroup | No of days events occurred | Events in the year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Events A | 6 | 6 |
| Events B | 4 | 4 |
| Events C | 6 | 6 |

I used the WITH statement and common table expression in SQL server to achieve this, please help me do something equivalent in DAX.

Comment: Use the SUMMARIZECOLUMNS function. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax

Comment: Subgroup A has 5 events on one day and 1 event on another.  In your output, shouldn't Subgroup Events A show Nu of days events occurred = 2?  Is Events in the year specific to 2023?  Wouldn't that be 1?  Maybe describe the problem better.